# With whom did Abel and Seth marry?

Tags: bible, genesis, adam-and-eve, seth

Adam and Eve have two sons, Abel and Cain.
[Cain slew Abel](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/bd/Peter_Paul_Rubens_-_Cain_slaying_Abel%2C_1608-1609.jpg/220px-Peter_Paul_Rubens_-_Cain_slaying_Abel%2C_1608-1609.jpg) because of jealousy.
Then Genesis 4, Cain got married, but to whom? 
Adam and eve were the first two persons in this world and that makes their sons the third and fourth person.

With whom did Abel and later his younger brother Seth got married.

Comment: I think it was Cain who killed Abel. In any case, you need to re-frame your question to fit in with the site rules.

Comment: See also: [With whom did Cain and Abel marry?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/27116/21576)

Comment: You may wish to familiarize yourself with the ancient tradition of jests regarding shepherds and their flocks.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Does that have anything to do with socks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question assumes a literal young-earth, literal creation and Adam and Eve as the literal first and only people interpretation of Scripture, so this answer comes from that view.

The common response from pretty much every Apologetic YEC organization is that they married their sisters. There were no other women in the world. And besides that, there were no laws forbidding marriage between brothers and sisters, but had there been; only God was in authority at the time, and he already knew.

As explained on  [ChristianAnswers.Net](http://www.christiananswers.net/q-aig/aig-c004.html)

> ...Even though only these three males are mentioned by name, Adam and Eve
>   had other children. In Genesis 5:4 a statement sums up the life of
>   Adam and Eve—“And the days of Adam after he had fathered Seth were
>   eight hundred years. And he fathered sons and daughters.” This does
>   not say when they were born. Many could have been born in the 130
>   years (Genesis 5:3) before Seth was born....

Also from [biblestudy.org](http://www.biblestudy.org/question/who-did-cain-and-abel-marry.html)

> ANSWER: The debate over who became the wife of man's first two
>   children has gone on for centuries. The short answer is that the
>   brothers had to marry their sisters. Man was, at first, only two
>   people, Adam and Eve. The couple's first three children were Cain,
>   Abel and Seth: "After he begot Seth, were eight hundred years; and he
>   had sons and daughters" (Genesis 5:4).
>
> How many sisters were potentially available for Cain and Abel to
>   marry? The Bible does not reveal exactly how many children Adam and
>   Eve produced. It is safe to assume, however, that since Adam lived 930
>   years, he had PLENTY of time to take full advantage of God's command
>   to procreate and fill the earth!

And the answer to the prohibition against Incest is consistent among apologetic groups.

For future research, I recommend a Bing or Google search on "Who did Cain marry".  You'll find that the answers that you find from those who hold the literal interpretation of Genesis, the answer is consistent.

Comment: Can you offer some scriptural or other doctrinal (or scholarly) support for this?

Comment: The laws against incest weren't put into place until Moses' time, so there was no law to break at that time.

Comment: It seems fine that they married their sister , but there is no clear evidence to support this.can you please put some reference to support your argument

Comment: I hope you don't mind but I edited some references into your answer to bring it up to site guidelines.  Remember that we focus on what Christian groups teach.  I gave a few examples of those teachings with references.

Comment: @David Of course I do not mind, any answer I give is with the expectation that it will either be elaborated on or corrected as necessary. I do not consider myself an authority on Christianity I do feel that I have a fair knowledge of the Bible, but even that is not infallible.